# How to select users with their amount list and sum amount using SUM(CASE) with a date interval

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table which contains list of users and the amount they save per day. I want to select all the money they save per day and also list all their details(amount) they have saved.

Issue: I couldn't find the sum for that date interval

[image]

```
SELECT 
cust_name,
ac_no,
amount,
SUM(CASE WHEN (trans_date > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)) 
THEN amount ELSE 0 END) as todalTotal from contributions
where username = 'james12'
GROUP BY id
```

This is what I am trying to achieve

```
$que = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT  cust_name,
ac_no,
amount FROM contributions
 WHERE username='$username' 
"
);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($que))
{

$sql =mysqli_query($con,"SELECT SUM(amount) as total FROM contributions WHERE trans_date > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 3 DAY) AND username='$username' ");

$rows = mysqli_fetch_array($sql);

echo $rows["total"] . "<br>";
echo $row["cust_name"] . "<br>";
}
```

> **$rows["total"]** will appear the number of times 
>   **$row["cust_name"]** appears which I don't want. I want 
>   **$rows["total"]** to appear just once.

Comment: could you show the `trans_date` column format?

Comment: @HastaDhana, Pls check my update.

Comment: I think your interval works fine, what result do you get? is there any record for username `james12`?

Answer (score 0):

You have to select the column and then tell where this is located. Then just use use SUM.

```sql
SELECT SUM(amount) AS AmountSaved
FROM yourtable
```

[SQL database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Cls7.png)

Comment: I could do that but I need to fetch it using date interval.

Comment: Aaaah you need pr. user i see?

Comment: Try to show the whole database, and specify a little more what you expect, that would help. I don't think it sound that difficult, I just think i misunderstood the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
select user_name,sum(amount) as total_amount,date_format(trans_date,'%Y-%d-%m') as transDate
from table_name
group by user_name,date_format(trans_date,'%Y-%d-%m')
```

Comment: You want data per day wise or month wise.Can you please show me the output that you want?